# Error de análisis: error de sintaxis, 'o' inesperado (T_STRING) en D: \ xampp \ htdocs \ variable \ conex.php en la línea 13

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de conectarme a la base de datos con este código php. sin embargo lo único que consigo es el siguiente error

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'o' (T_STRING) in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\bariable\conex.php on line 13"

no se si alguien pueda ayudarme gracias

```
<?php 
    //Sintaxis de conexión de la base de datos de muestra para PHP y MySQL.

    //Conectar a la base de datos

    $hostname="your_hostname";
    $username="your_dbusername";
    $password="your_dbpassword";
    $dbname="your_dbusername";
    $usertable="your_tablename";
    $yourfield = "your_field";

    mysql_connect($hostname,$username, $password) o morir ("html>script language='JavaScript'>alert('¡No es posible conectarse a la base de datos! Vuelve a intentarlo más tarde.'),history.go(-1)/script>/html>");
    mysql_select_db($dbname);

    # Comprobar si existe registro

    $query = “SELECCIONAR * DESDE $usertable”;

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    si($result){
        mientras que($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $name = $row["$yourfield"];
            echo "Nombre: ".$name."br/>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: de donde obtuviste esa función llamada morir()? dentro de la documentación en español no existe, es or die()

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Oscar tu código PHP parece que fue metido en un traductor ¿? `morir, SELECCIONAR, si, mientras ...` el intérprete no habla español, todo eso debe ser escrito en inglés. Esas comillas `“`  tampoco se pueden usar... Y revisa la fuente de donde estás aprendiendo, pues usa código muyyyy viejo, y funciones obsoletas como es el caso de la extensión `mysql_*`

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un error al momento de usar las funciones de conexión; deben ser así

```
    mysql_connect($hostname,$username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($dbname);
```

> Donde como puedes notar paso dentro de la función el método
>   mysql_error() que me va a regresar el motivo por el cual no se pudo
>   conectar a la base de datos

Del mismo modo te indico que estas usando una función de conexión insegura y descontinuada; deberías usar en su lugar **mysqli** o **PDO**; puedes checar mas información aquí

http://php.net/manual/es/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

> Las funciones y palabras reservadas de cualquier lenguaje de
>   programación o gestor de bases de datos no se traducen al español, es
>   decir se mantiene su declaración en inglés

Comment: No se si es en este lugar, donde se agradece la ayuda. si no es así disculpen. A Alfredo mi agradecimiento por tomarse el tiempo de responder mi consulta mil gracias